# Code first Entity Framework foreign key constraint

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

`Property.cs` has `PaymentDetailId` but not assigned as foreign key during migration

```
    public long CountryId { get; set; }
    public virtual Country Country { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public bool IsDeleted { get; set; }
    public int RoomsAvailable { get; set; }

    [DefaultValue(0), Required]
    public int Order { get; set; }

    public long? PaymentDetailId { get; set; }
    public virtual PaymentDetail PaymentDetail { get; set; }
```

`PaymentDetail.cs` has `PropertyId` is a  foreign key in PaymentDetails but PaymentDetailId is not foreign key in Properties table

```
     public long PropertyId { get; set; }
    public virtual Property Property { get; set; }

    [StringLength(200)]
    public string AccountNumber { get; set; }
    [StringLength(100)]
    public string IFSCCode { get; set; }
    [StringLength(200)]
    public string Name { get; set; }
```

Fluent api added:

```
 protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
 {
     modelBuilder.Entity<Property>().HasOptional(p =>p.PaymentDetail).
     WithRequired(d => d.Property).WillCascadeOnDelete();
     base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
 }
```

Encountered the following error:

> The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_dbo.PaymentDetails_dbo.Properties_Id". The conflict occurred in database "QikStay.DAL.QikStayDataContext", table "dbo.Properties", column 'Id'.

Migration File :

```
 public partial class propertypaymentdetail : DbMigration
{
    public override void Up()
    {
        CreateTable(
            "dbo.PaymentDetails",
            c => new
                {
                    Id = c.Long(nullable: false),
                    PropertyId = c.Long(nullable: false),
                    AccountNumber = c.String(maxLength: 200),
                    IFSCCode = c.String(maxLength: 100),
                    Name = c.String(maxLength: 200),
                    CreateTime = c.DateTime(nullable: false, precision: 7, storeType: "datetime2"),
                    UpdateTime = c.DateTime(nullable: false, precision: 7, storeType: "datetime2"),
                })
            .PrimaryKey(t => t.Id)
            .ForeignKey("dbo.Properties", t => t.Id)
            .Index(t => t.Id);

        AddColumn("dbo.Properties", "PaymentDetailId", c => c.Long());
    }

    public override void Down()
    {
        DropForeignKey("dbo.PaymentDetails", "Id", "dbo.Properties");
        DropIndex("dbo.PaymentDetails", new[] { "Id" });
        DropColumn("dbo.Properties", "PaymentDetailId");
        DropTable("dbo.PaymentDetails");
    }
}
```

}

This is the correct fluent api that solved issue

> 

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Property>()
 .HasOptional(a => a.PaymentDetail)
 .WithMany()
 .HasForeignKey(u => u.PaymentDetailId);
```

Comment: We get the warning a lot and we have been ignoring it.  Code still works.

Comment: You are getting error because there IS a FK constraint, that seems to be created on correct columns: PaymentDetails_Properties. Why you are stating that FK is not assigned during migration? Please provide migration code.

Comment: I am not able to see the foreign key relationship for PaymentDetailId in Properties table and when I am inserting PaymentDetail data it throws an error stating conflict FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_dbo.PaymentDetails_dbo.Properties_Id"

Comment: I solved the issue using fluent api as one-one foreign key relations: